# Why XMLStarlet replaces '>' to '&gt;' in a string?

Tags: xml, freeswitch, xmlstarlet

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html) editing by:

`xmlstarlet ed -O -u "/include/X-PRE-PROCESS[@cmd='set' and starts-with(@data,'domain=')]/@data" -v 'domain=test.domain' vars.xml`

on a target file:

```
<include>
    <X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="domain=domain.com"/>
    <X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="bong-ring=v=-7;%(100,0,941.0,1477.0);v=-7;>=2;+=.1;%(1400,0,350,440)"/>
</include>
```

changes necessary `data="domain=domain.com"` value,
 
but also returns unexpected (for me) change of `>` to `&gt;` in a string value `bong-ring=...` so `>=2` becomes `&gt;=2`

```
<include>
    <X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="domain=test.domain"/>
    <X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="bong-ring=v=-7;%(100,0,941.0,1477.0);v=-7;&gt;=2;+=.1;%(1400,0,350,440)"/>
</include>
```

Isn't `">"` protected by quotes `""`?

So the question is:

Is there a bug in XMLStarlet or it's a bug in an application ([Freeswitch](http://freeswitch.org) v1.7) which uses vars.xml and parses
`<X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="bong-ring=v=-7;%(100,0,941.0,1477.0);v=-7;&gt;=2;+=.1;%(1400,0,350,440)"/>`
as
`v=-7;%(100,0,941.0,1477.0);v=-7;&gt;=2;+=.1;%(1400,0,350,440)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with XMLStarlet doing this.

The notion that `>` is being "protected" by the quotes is wrong. Technically `>` is *legal* in attribute values, as opposed to `<`, which is illegal (so is `>` in text node values).

Usually tools escape the XML-reserved characters regardless of context<sup>(*)</sup>, so text nodes will contain `&gt;` and attributes will contain `&gt;` as well. There is nothing wrong with this.

However, in essence *every single character* in an attribute value or text node value may be escaped.

The following is completely legal XML that is 100% equivalent to both of your samples:

```
<include>
    <X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="&#x73;&#x65;&#x74;" data="&#x64;&#x6f;&#x6d;&#x61;&#x69;&#x6e;&#x3d;&#x74;&#x65;&#x73;&#x74;&#x2e;&#x64;&#x6f;&#x6d;&#x61;&#x69;&#x6e;"/>
    <X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="&#x73;&#x65;&#x74;" data="&#x62;&#x6f;&#x6e;&#x67;&#x2d;&#x72;&#x69;&#x6e;&#x67;&#x3d;&#x76;&#x3d;&#x2d;&#x37;&#x3b;&#x25;&#x28;&#x31;&#x30;&#x30;&#x2c;&#x30;&#x2c;&#x39;&#x34;&#x31;&#x2e;&#x30;&#x2c;&#x31;&#x34;&#x37;&#x37;&#x2e;&#x30;&#x29;&#x3b;&#x76;&#x3d;&#x2d;&#x37;&#x3b;&#x3e;&#x3d;&#x32;&#x3b;&#x2b;&#x3d;&#x2e;&#x31;&#x3b;&#x25;&#x28;&#x31;&#x34;&#x30;&#x30;&#x2c;&#x30;&#x2c;&#x33;&#x35;&#x30;&#x2c;&#x34;&#x34;&#x30;&#x29;"/>
</include>
```

It comes down to this: XML is not a string. Don't treat it as one. Don't use or create tools that treat XML as a string. XML requires a parser - and all conforming parsers will do the right thing in this situation.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> From the point of view of an XML serializer: a) Generating different output for attribute values and text nodes makes the serialization process more complex without adding any value to the result. b) It's easier to write a single function for XML-escaping any string and then re-use it. c) Symmetry is easier to handle in general and programmers tend to like it.

Comment: @kjhughes Re: [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33236700/revisions#rev-arrow-ccf030a2-0b60-45ba-a1c5-de97f10a9a48): Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a non-conforming parser, just as there is no such thing as "almost XML". It's XML, or not. And it's an XML parser - or not. :)

Comment: No such things: "almost XML."  Agreed.  However, "non-conforming *parsers*" can exist (and do during development and, unfortunately, beyond).  Now, about those angels dancing on the head of a pin...    :)

Comment: An almost-parser can parse almost-XML. That is all-right, but then we are not talking about XML and not about an XML parser. Yes, it's hairsplitting, I know. I left the edit in for that reason. :)

Comment: Hey, I imitated [fancy standards language](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-conformance) and had an edit accepted by @Tomalak.  I'm having a great day!

Comment: Uhh, that was too much irony for a single comment.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. There is no problem with the XML tool. I've got an answer from the Freeswitch community. They don't support special characters with their preparser.

Comment: My guess would be that their "preparser" is regex-based. Why people keep using XML for their config files and then something that's not an XML parser to read those files eludes me.